# Python Webscraping with BeautifulSoup : It shows 0s instead of real values

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract 'like' count values on a music-chart web site named melon. And there are count values on browser and dev tools like this.

[image: Web site view]

But on the source code page there are just 0s instead of like count values on a tag that have like count value like this.

[image: Source code page]

So when I run my `BeautifulSoup` code, it just shows 0 values.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://www.melon.com/chart/#params%5Bidx%5D=51',
                headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome 77.0.3865.120'}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title = soup.select('button > span.cnt')
```

[image: Result]

How can I get the real values like on the website numbers instead of 0s?

I'm really shy about my coding and English skills but I really would like to learn how to make a data analysis automation program. So I hope you to help a poor learner :)

Thanks!

Comment: The website might be loading data dynamically via javascript so you cant access the date until its in browser. You may use selenium webdriver and try the same to exctract data which renders js just as any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned by Pavan, the webpage is loading the content dynamically, to account for this, you can use **Selenium**, which is used for browser automation, you can still pass the HTML object to BeautifulSoup afterwards if you still wish to use soup selectors.